# Removing the "Powered by WordPress" Link?

Tags: licensing

Am I allowed to remove the *"Powered by WordPress"* link in the footer?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Yes WordPress is licensed using the [**GPL v2 license**](http://www.gnu.org/philosophy/free-sw.html) so you are *"free"* to do whatever you want to with it ([*"free"* as in *"free speech"*, not *"free"* as in *"free beer!"*](http://www.gnu.org/philosophy/free-sw.html).)

Answer (score 15):

Yes, and an easy way to suppress it, without modifying the actual HTML, is to use the following custom CSS:

```
#site-generator {
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: +1, this is interesting solution - apparently this option will leave the SEO goodness for wordpress.com while not visually telling every user that the site is running on WordPress (not that this would be the aim:))

Answer (score 2):

The plugin Adminimize has an option for this

Comment: *@bueltge* - I think I've heard of that plugin... so who wrote it? ;-)

Comment: actually has the plugin to much options, it is to big for me and a great support. I will write a smaller version with the new possibilities of WP 2.9 and higher. I had write this plugin for an long time and the community wouldnt so much options and many options is now not required. Actully it works and the nect great version was a rewrite.

Answer (score 1):

The other option is to remove it entirely from functions.php. Search in functions.php for "*powered*" and take out the portion of code reading: `. Powered by [wp-link].`

Comment: Could work, but in a lot of themes the credits link is hard-coded in footer.php. Check there as well.

Answer (score 1):

Yes WordPress is licensed using the GPL v2 license so you are "free" to do whatever you want to with it. The plugin Adminimize has an option for this

Answer (score 1):

Since you didn't specify a theme , I'll assume you are using the default theme, now *TwentyEleven*, or one that is similarly built.

In the theme's root directory, you will find the footer.php file. Look for the following html:

```
<div id="site-generator">
            <?php do_action( 'twentyeleven_credits' ); ?>
            <a href="<?php echo esc_url( __( 'http://wordpress.org/', 'twentyeleven' ) ); ?>" title="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Semantic Personal Publishing Platform', 'twentyeleven' ); ?>" rel="generator"><?php printf( __( 'Proudly powered by %s', 'twentyeleven' ), 'WordPress' ); ?></a>
</div>
```

Delete it, and save the file, or you can replace it with your own link like so:

```
<div id="footer-links">
    <a href="<?php echo home_url( '/' ); ?>" title="<?php bloginfo( 'name' ); ?>" rel="home'><?php bloginfo( 'name' ); ?></a>
</div><!-- #footer-links -->
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's how to remove or modify the footer text in the WP admin, put this into `functions.php` of your theme :

```
function modify_admin_footer () {
  echo 'Developped by <a href="http://www.mycompany.com" target="_blank">My company</a>';
}
add_filter('admin_footer_text', 'modify_admin_footer');
```