# How do I white label my self-hosted site created by wordpress?

Tags: themes

I have seen code in an answer to this [question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/1059?tab=newest#tab-top), how to remove the promotional back link to WordPress.org in my theme.  I have added this to my theme's CSS but there is no change.

Am I missing see some thing? Apologies for my Ignorance .

Code I have used:

```
#site-generator {
display: none; }
```

How can you remove the widgets from dashboard and add new customized widgets ?
Is there possibility to hide the date and time from posts ?

**Update** :Could anybody tell me ,If I can remove the term 'wordpress' from displaying on title bar?

Comment: @Thomas McDonald                                                        How do you call this question as  "question is not specfic to 3.0.1" ?

Comment: @user391 The question is about functionality that is common to a wide range of WordPress versions.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here is the code I always use whenever I setup a new wordpress blog:

CUSTOM ADMIN FOOTER TEXT

```
// CUSTOMIZE ADMIN FOOTER TEXT
   function custom_admin_footer() {
    echo '<a href="http://www.netconstructor.com/">Website Design by NetConstructor, Inc.</a>';
   }
   add_filter('admin_footer_text', 'custom_admin_footer');
```

REMOVE VERSION INFO FROM THE HEAD OF FEEDS

```
// REMOVE VERSION INFO FROM THE HEAD OF FEEDS
   function complete_version_removal() { return ''; }
   add_filter('the_generator', 'complete_version_removal');
```

REMOVE JUNK FROM THE HEADER OF PUBLIC WEBSITE PAGES

```
// REMOVE JUNK FROM THE HEADER OF PUBLIC WEBSITE PAGES
   remove_action('wp_head', 'rsd_link');
   remove_action('wp_head', 'wp_generator');
   remove_action('wp_head', 'feed_links', 2);
   remove_action('wp_head', 'index_rel_link');
   remove_action('wp_head', 'wlwmanifest_link');
   remove_action('wp_head', 'feed_links_extra', 3);
   remove_action('wp_head', 'start_post_rel_link', 10, 0);
   remove_action('wp_head', 'parent_post_rel_link', 10, 0);
   remove_action('wp_head', 'adjacent_posts_rel_link', 10, 0);
```

REMOVE THE WORDPRESS UPDATE NOTIFICATION FOR ALL USERS EXCEPT SYSADMIN

```
// REMOVE THE WORDPRESS UPDATE NOTIFICATION FOR ALL USERS EXCEPT SYSADMIN
   global $user_login;
   get_currentuserinfo();
   if ($user_login !== "sysadmin") {
    add_action( 'init', create_function( '$a', "remove_action( 'init', 'wp_version_check' );" ), 2 );
    add_filter( 'pre_option_update_core', create_function( '$a', "return null;" ) );
   }
```

CUSTOM ADMIN LOGOS:

```
// CUSTOM ADMIN LOGIN HEADER LOGO
   function my_custom_login_logo() {
    echo '<style type="text/css"> h1 a { background-image:url('.get_bloginfo('template_directory').'/images/excitesteps-login-logo.png) !important; } </style>';
   }
   add_action('login_head', 'my_custom_login_logo');



// CUSTOM ADMIN LOGIC HEADER LOGO
   add_action('admin_head', 'my_custom_logo');
   function my_custom_logo() {
    echo '<style type="text/css">#header-logo { background-image: url('.get_bloginfo('template_directory').'/images/excitesteps-icon.gif) !important; }</style>';
   }



// CUSTOM ADMIN LOGIN HEADER LINK & ALT TEXT
   function change_wp_login_url() {
    echo bloginfo('url');
   }
   function change_wp_login_title() {
    echo get_option('blogname');
   }
   add_filter('login_headerurl', 'change_wp_login_url');
   add_filter('login_headertitle', 'change_wp_login_title');
```

Comment: whoa, great idea.

Comment: Really a great recipe .I won't forget it

Comment: thanks guys - i would appreciate if you would vote it up

Comment: Am I need to set it up in every theme? Are there any possibilities to use it site wide rather than adding the code to each theme ?

Comment: I add these records into the functions.php file for every theme. If your talking about running wordpress in multi-site mode I believe there is a way to create a functions.php file which applies to all themes but I am not positive.

Comment: Yeah ! I am talking about multisites . It would be better If I can able to apply to all the themes .

Comment: No problem If there is no way ! I can do it theme wise.

Comment: Assuming that you include lets say 50 wordpress themes for your multi-site deployment my suggestion would be to add a php include into the functions file for each of your wordpress themes with some "general" custom functions you want to set for each of your themes and then modify this single include file to set such preferences globally :-)

Comment: @NetConstuctor.com This would make a great plugin and wouldn't that also solve the problem of having to include it in every theme?

Comment: I would agree unless there is already some type of built in capability which I am unaware of in wordpress which allows a single functions file manage a "network". I might suggest that you take a look at that default network plugin which automatically gets created when you wordpress ms (network) is enabled. If I remember correctly the plugin/file is called sunrise.php but I never looked into that functionality.

Answer (score 1):

"site-generator" is the div id assigned to the Powered by WordPress link in Twentyten, the default theme.  Many other themes also contain a powered by WordPress link in the footer but might not assign the same div id as Twentyten.

To find the div id or class assigned to the the link in the footer of your theme you can view source from your browser and scroll down to the bottom of the page.  When you find the link to WordPress.org look for the `<div>` tag that the wraps the link and take note of the id or class assigned to it.

Example from the Retromania Theme:

```
<div class="copy">&copy; Theme Preview 2009 | Created by <a href="http://www.jayhafling.com/">Jay Hafling</a>.</div>

                    <div class="copy_support">Powered by <a href="http://www.wordpress.org/">WordPress</a></div>
```

In this example the class "copy_support" is assigned to the powered by link so to remove it you would ass this to your css:

```
.copy_support {
display:none;
}
```

Since it is a class and not an id you use the `.` selector instead of the `#`

Comment: Done ! It worked well for me :)

Answer (score 1):

When doing it with CSS, make sure you are using firebug to see if the rule you are trying to apply is being applied to the element. It could be that there is a more specific rule, an equally specific but later defined rule, or even an inline rule overriding that your custom rule.

Comment: Thank you for your advice .                                              I will keep it in mind .

Answer (score -1):

This plugin works pretty well http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/white-label-cms/

Comment: Lone link is considered a poor answer (see [FAQ#deletion]) since it is meaningless by itself and target resource is not guaranteed to be alive in the future. Please try to include at least summary of information you are linking to.