# Wordpress Copyright Dillema (i.e. Powered by)

Tags: licensing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Removing the “Powered by WordPress” Link?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/1059/removing-the-powered-by-wordpress-link)

i have a bit odd question but here it goes: Due to page styling issues with the copyright logo, i deleted the whole div that says: "Powered by Wordpress (logo)". Now due to my SEO plugin, the source doesn't include the meta-generator tag. Now am i in violation of the Wordpress License, or im ok (although i do look irresponsible)?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is no requirement to retain the "Powered by WordPress" note in the footer or the WordPress reference in the `<meta>` tags in your header.  There is nothing in the WordPress license (GPL) that requires these remain intact.

To take things a bit further ... the "Powered by WordPress" tag in the footer is added by your *theme*, not by WordPress itself.  And the `<meta>` tag in the header is pluggable specifically to make it easy to remove.

Comment: Yes i know its in themes only, but i thought i should carry it over. But then it turned out that it doesn't fit the page's visual styles, so it was removed.

Comment: Just a matter of preference.  If you can work it into your design, that's fantastic.  If not, try not to sweat it too much.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't delete the meta-generator tag, its used to have the stats of number of WP sites running. Though you can remove the Powered by WordPress. Matt doesn't like meta generator tag being removed. :)

Removing none of those is a violation until you remove the License that comes with WordPress or try to not give the credit to original WordPress developers in your modified WordPress if you are re-distributing it.

As @EAMann said there is nothing in license, but keeping the meta generator tag is the least you can do to thank efforts put in to WordPress Development.

**UPDATE**: A [Ticket discussing meta generator](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/12495) tag on Wordpress trac.

**UPDATE 2:** Just for the record that Matt reference I used in my answer is because I envy Matt and I really honor him for giving away such a great software for free (both in money and in freedom). So, what ever he says about WordPress means a lot to me, you can totally ignore that if you don't feel like this. I am still looking for the link to the blog post in which Matt had an argument with a blogger regarding his advice on securing Wordpress by removing meta generator tag, will share it here as soon as I find it.

Comment: "Shouldn't" is a matter of preference.  Yes, it's useful for stats to some people, but so are aggregate downloads of the platform.  The *problem* with the `<meta>` tag arises if you neglect to stay up-to-date with security updates.  If WP releases an urgent update, and you miss the notice or skip a version, the `<meta>` tag is just advertising that you're running an insecure build.

Comment: Hm EAMann really makes a point, the website can't be updated right away when there is an update and i prefer to count one site less then having a possible security problems.

Comment: I agree that its the personal preference, but it can't save you from a security attack if your are running an unpatched version, Because if an attacker don't see the generator tag he will surely try all the Wordpress exploits to his disposal for all previous wordpress versions. I think they will even try those on the newer and patched version too anyway.

Comment: But the meta tag appears in serach engines type in power by wordpress and you will surely have a list of sites pop up now remove the meta tag and your site is less likely to pop up now. Thus making it harder for a hacker to find your site. Hameedullah Khan are you a hacker? Do not pick a fight. Worpdress keeps tabs on how many sites are downloaded. Now since you can block search engines i highly doubt one little tag is going to keep stats accurate.

Comment: @xLRDxREVENGEx I wish if I was a hacker (a true one). I have never liked Security through obscurity. As @EAMann said its matter of personal choice, so I stated what I think about it and why I keep it there always.

Comment: Just updated my answer with the link to related ticket on Wordpress trac.

Comment: "*Matt wants/likes...*" or "*Matt doesn't want/like...*" are utterly specious and irrelevant arguments. Free Software Philosophy is all about what the **end user** wants, *at the expense of what the **developer** wants*.

Comment: It's not about security-through-obscurity (I agree with the arguments that retaining or removing the generator meta tag will make absolutely no difference in site security.) The real issue is *user freedom*. Under no circumstances should users be compelled to do *anything* simply because the developer desires them to do so. Such compulsion (guilt trips, appeals to ethical/moral concerns, etc.) utterly contradict Free Software Philosophy.

Comment: @Chip Bennett I agree its all about the freedom and this is what I said in my answer that Wordpress license doesn't stop you from removing neither meta generator tag and neither Powered by Wordpress. Keeping the generator tag is one's own preference but in my view its the least an end user can do to thanks developers for giving us such a great piece of software for free.

Comment: WordPress.org doesn't use the generator tag for any sort of stats, FYI. Other web-scanning and polling systems (non-WordPress ones) do use that information. Example: http://w3techs.com/technologies/overview/content_management/all